# Matlab: Axis labels in surfc

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am ploting a surface using `surfc` and I can not see my axis labels.

[image]

Can you help me aligning the `xlabel` and `ylabel` to the axes and try to visualize them?

```
surf(X,Y,surface);
colorbar
shading interp
xlabel('Induction factor a1');
ylabel('Induction factor a2');
zlabel('Coefficient')
title('Curve')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the image is made there is only one option. There is rotate button on the top you can use it according to your requirement and to check for alignment.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Either you can rotate the image after its been generated, or you can specify the angle that you want to rotate in your code by the following code,

```
     set(get(gca,'Induction factor a1'),'rotation',thetax);
     set(get(gca,'Induction factor a2'),'rotation',thetay);
     set(get(gca,'Coefficient'),'rotation',thetaz);
```

You can specify the required angles by which you want to rotate the labels in thetaz, thetay & thetaz.